Decoding CAN Data for LEVs
I'm a research student working on chargers for light electric vehicles (LEVs). I've built an in-house charger for 48V with a maximum current of 40A, and I’m testing it with various autorickshaws and two-wheelers in real-world conditions. One challenge I'm facing is that LEVs use a CAN protocol to communicate with chargers about their voltage and current needs, but there isn't a standard protocol like there is for cars. I’ve tried looking into protocols like SAE J1939, IEC 61850-24, and IS 17017-24, but none of them match. Can anyone suggest other protocols that LEVs might be using? Also, is there a way to decode the raw CAN data that I’m collecting during these tests?
Note: No I cannot test this on any test bench setup as this is supposed to be a field trial.
P.S. I am new at posting questions hence forgive any improper writing skills

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! :o)
